# Set NSString with returned JSON value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to set my imageView with the url returned in the JSON data below in "value" (secondLink). When I use the following code, it returns the entire block in JSON through my XCode console - what should my code look like if I ONLY want the image's URL to be returned (right now, I assume it's trying to set the imageView with EVERYTHING returned in secondLink)?

**ViewController.m**

```
NSString *secondLink = [[[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"field_photo_path"] objectForKey:@"safe_value"];

    NSLog(@"This is second link %@", secondLink);

    if([secondLink length]>0) {


    NSString *ImageURL = secondLink;
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


  } else {

    NSString *ImageURL = @"defaulturl.com";
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

**JSON data**

```
{
    und =     (
                {
            format = "<null>";
            "safe_value" = "http://myurl.com/sites/default/files/stored/photo.jpg";
            value = "http://myurl.com/sites/default/files/stored/photo.jpg";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: So this line `NSLog(@"This is second link %@", secondLink);` is printing the entire JSON block you posted?

Comment: Post a JSON in its natural form

Comment: Also, what's the point of the XML? Do you need to parse that as well?

Comment: Deleting [your post right after somebody takes the trouble to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36241879/603977) is kind of rude. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `field_photo_path` there is a dictionary `und` which contains an array.
The first item in the array is a dictionary containing the key `safe_value`.

It assumes that `user` is also a dictionary (at least it responds to `objectForKey:`)

```
NSDictionary *user = [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user];
NSString *secondLink = user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

Comment: Yes I would do the same thing, but I wonder why she have this key in quotation not like other entries

Comment: probably posted the wrongly formatted data what she's getting back now

Comment: Or maybe this key should look like this: `@"\"safe_value\""`

Comment: @MarekR That's the standard dictionary `NSLog`/`print` representation which quotes every key containing non-alphanumeric characters.